# Calculating destination point using Python

Tags: python, distance, coordinates, origin-destination

I am trying to write a function that calculates the GPS (decimal) coordinates of a point that is far of a given distance from a given point.
Let say that we start from *point 1* (The stripe of Dublin) and we want to move 25km east.

This is what I have written:

```
import math 
# Coordinates of "The Spire" (Dublin)
lat1_dg=53.34972
lon1_dg=-6.26028
bearing=90 #degree from North
distance=25000 # distance in meter
alpha = math.radians(bearing)
radius=6371000 # radius of Earth (in meter)
gamma = distance / radius
lat1_r= math.radians(lat1_dg)
lon1_r= math.radians(lon1_dg)
Δlat_r = gamma * math.cos(alpha)
lat2_r = lat1_r + Δlat_r
Δlon_r = gamma * math.sin(alpha)/math.cos(lat1_r)
lon2_r = lon1_r + Δlon_r
lat2_dg=(math.degrees(lat2_r))
lon2_dg=(math.degrees(lon2_r))
print(lat2_dg,lon2_dg)
```

This outputs the following, which is close to the correct answer

> 53.349720000000005 -5.883634969206713

but if I calculate the distance between *point 1* and *point 2* with [this](https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/) tool, I get 25.008 meters...why?

Comment: Can you paste your distance code here please ?

Comment: For the distance I have used this tool https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/ (now it is also linked in my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your units in the Andrew Hedges Haversine tool - it gives me 25.008 **km** !  (or 15.543 miles)

(also by just looking at your coords, you can see it should be 10s of km and not metres - a degree is usually somewhere in the 50-100km range - this is a *very* rough approximation but gives you a clue)